# Need to find the count of user who belongs to different depts

Tags: sql

---

I have table with dept,user and so on, I need to find the number of count of user that belongs to different combinations of the dept.

Lets consider I've a table like this:

```
dept   user  
1      33  
1      33  
1      45  
2      11  
2      12   
3      33  
3      15
```

Then I've to find the uniq user and dept combination: something like this:
select distinct dept,user from x;

Which will give me result like :

```
Dept    user  
1         33  
1         45  
2         11  
2         12  
3         33  
3         15
```

which actually removes the duplicates of the combination:
And here's the thing which i need to do :

My output should look like this:

```
dep_1_1 dep_1_2 dep_1_3 dep_2_2 dep_2_1 dep_2_3 Dep_3_1 Dep_3_2 Dep_3_3  
2          0     1       2       0         0      1       0      2
```

So, Basically I need to find the count of common users between all the combinations of departments

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please edit your question and tag the DBMS you're using. Also consider to add the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table and `INSERT INTO` statements for the sample data. Please also include the query you have tried so far.

Comment: This is called a PIVOT. You should also specify if you have a limited and static number of departments or if there are thousand of them... in which case do you want thousand of columns?

Comment: Hi @ThomasG   I've around 60 depts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a row for each department combination using a self-join of your Distinct Select:

```
with cte as
 (
   select distinct dept,user from x 
 )
select t1.dept, t2.dept, count(*)
from cte a st1 join cte as t2
  on t1.user = t2.user -- same user
 and t1.dept < t2.dept -- different department
group by t1.dept, t2.dept
order by t1.dept, t2.dept
```

Comment: Hi @dnoeth, it worked like a charm. thanks for the help mate

Comment: @MukeshMarimuthu do your duty and accept the answer if it answered the question